# How to output a list in a string?

Tags: r

I have a list called `birthdays` which contains numbers.
I would like to output the first 5 within a string, i.e

> Birthdays: 1,2,3,4,5

I have done this:

```r
paste("Birthdays: ",head(birthdays,6))
```

However this outputs:

> "Birthdays: 1" "Birthdays: 2" "Birthdays: 3" "Birthdays: 4" "Birthdays: 5"

And I would like it to output:
"Birthdays: 1,2,3,4,5" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `collapse=` argument to `paste`: this concatenates the elements in a vector (you need a separate `paste` call for this).

```r
paste("Birthdays: ",paste(head(birthdays,6),collapse=","))
```

If you literally want to *output* rather than save the value in a variable, try

```r
cat("Birthdays:",paste(1:5,collapse=","),"\n")
```